# Почему C# разрешил скомпилировать конструктор без параметров?

Tags: c#, .net

**В книге Рихтера, о теме: "Конструкторы экземпляров и структуры (значимые типы)".**
Так как компилятор не генерирует автоматически для структур их конструкторы без параметров, то поля инициализируются 0/Null, и что бы принудительно исполнить конструктор значимого типа без параметров, то его нужно явно объявить, иначе как написано в книге данный код даже нельзя скомпилировать.

**Пример кода из книги Рихтера:**

```
internal struct Point {
public Int32 m_x, m_y;
public Point() {
m_x = m_y = 5;
 }
}
internal sealed class Rectangle {
public Point m_topLeft, m_bottomRight;
public Rectangle() {
 }
}
```

Однако протестив данный код компилятор выдал мне такую ошибку по поводу структуры Point:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого я решил изменить версию языка до 10.0 и обратно протестировать данный код
и вуаля у меня все получилось. Почему получилось?

Код версии языка 10.0

```
var rect = new Rectangle();
Console.WriteLine(rect.ToString()); //блок метода Main

internal struct Point
{
    public Int32 m_x, m_y;
    public Point()
    {
        m_x = m_y = 5;
    }
}
internal sealed class Rectangle
{
    public Point m_topLeft, m_bottomRight;
    public Rectangle()
    {}
}

public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format($"{m_topLeft.m_x}, {m_topLeft.m_y} : {m_bottomRight.m_x}, 
{m_bottomRight.m_y}"); 
}
```

**.NET6 решили поменять шаблон консольного приложения** [Шаблон консольного приложения .NET6](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/tutorials/top-level-templates)

Comment: Потому что сначала нельзя было, потом майкрософт "а давайте конструкторы без параметров в структурах сделаем", вот и сделали. Книги устаревают даже во время их написания, а книга рихтера - 2013 год, многое поменялось